# How To Detect Keyboard Shortcuts like CTRL+S in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I would like to detect keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+S in Scala. It is easy if only one key is pressed, but it seems to be difficult if two or more keys are pressed. Is there any better solution than the following?

```
reactions += {
  case c @ KeyReleased(_, Key.S, _, _) =>
    if (c.peer.isControlDown())
      // CTRL+S pressed
}
```

It feels somehow semantically incorrect since it checks if the CTRL button is pressed after the S button is released (and I think it is not really better when you use `KeyPressed` or `KeyTyped`).

Here is a [SSCE](http://www.sscce.org/):

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

object SSCCE extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    val textArea = new TextArea(3, 30)
    contents = new FlowPanel {
      contents += textArea
    }
    listenTo(textArea.keys)
    reactions += {
      case c @ KeyReleased(_, Key.S, _, _) =>
        if (c.peer.isControlDown())
          Dialog.showMessage(null, "Message", "CTRL+S pressed")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check within the pattern match by testing the modifiers:

```
case c @ KeyReleased(_, Key.S, mods, _) if (1 == (1 & mods>>7)) =>
  Dialog.showMessage(null, "Message", "CTRL+S pressed")
```

When Ctrl is down, the bit at index 7 is set.

However, I think your original code is easier to understand.

Adding a helper function would help, of course:

```
def ctrlDown(mods:Int) = (1 == (1 & mods>>7))
...

case c @ KeyReleased(_, Key.S, mods, _) if ctrlDown(mods) =>
  Dialog.showMessage(null, "Message", "CTRL+S pressed")
```

Comment: Thanks. But yeah, I also think that this is even harder to understand... I think/thought there has to be a nicer, more scalable solution (for shortcuts with X key presses)...